# Trying to Install Kubernetes with Vagrant and Ansible on Ubuntu 16.04 lab

Tags: ansible, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, vagrant, calico

So I am trying to install Kubernetes on a lab with Vagrant and Ansible.
I am using the following documentation on Ubuntu 16.04:

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/15/kubernetes-setup-using-ansible-and-vagrant/

Several Problems I encounter:

1. The Vagrant File fails to initialize
2. The Node does not successfully provision the node IP Address with Extra Args
3. While specifying the documented version of Calico in the Ansible Playbook it fails.

For number 1, here is the vagrant file:

```
IMAGE_NAME = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
N = 2

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 1024
        v.cpus = 2
    end
      
    config.vm.define "k8s-master" do |master|
        master.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
        master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.10"
        master.vm.hostname = "k8s-master"
        master.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
            ansible.playbook = "kubernetes-setup/master-playbook.yml"
            ansible.extra_vars = {
                node_ip: "192.168.50.10",
            }
        end
    end

    (1..N).each do |i|
        config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
            node.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
            node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.#{i + 10}"
            node.vm.hostname = "node-#{i}"
            node.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
                ansible.playbook = "kubernetes-setup/node-playbook.yml"
                ansible.extra_vars = {
                    node_ip: "192.168.50.#{i + 10}",
                }
            end
        end
    end
```

Am I missing something within the `Vagrantfile`?

For number 2, I am seeing the following issue within the master-playbook.yaml, if fails at this step:

```
  - name: Configure node ip
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/default/kubelet
      line: KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip={{ node_ip }}
```

For number 3 I encountered an issue with the Calico Task within Ansible:

```
  - name: Install calico pod network
    become: false
    command: kubectl create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml
```

I get the following Message on that task:

```
TASK [Install calico pod network] **********************************************
fatal: [k8s-master]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["kubectl", "create", "-f", "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml"], "delta": "0:00:01.460979", "end": "2020-08-21 01:57:36.395550", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2020-08-21 01:57:34.934571", "stderr": "unable to recognize \"https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml\": no matches for kind \"DaemonSet\" in version \"extensions/v1beta1\"\nunable to recognize \"https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml\": no matches for kind \"Deployment\" in version \"extensions/v1beta1\"", "stderr_lines": ["unable to recognize \"https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml\": no matches for kind \"DaemonSet\" in version \"extensions/v1beta1\"", "unable to recognize \"https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml\": no matches for kind \"Deployment\" in version \"extensions/v1beta1\""], "stdout": "configmap/calico-config created\nsecret/calico-etcd-secrets created\nserviceaccount/calico-node created\nserviceaccount/calico-kube-controllers created\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-kube-controllers created\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-kube-controllers created\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-node created\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-node created", "stdout_lines": ["configmap/calico-config created", "secret/calico-etcd-secrets created", "serviceaccount/calico-node created", "serviceaccount/calico-kube-controllers created", "clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-kube-controllers created", "clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-kube-controllers created", "clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-node created", "clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-node created"]}

RUNNING HANDLER [docker status] ************************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/sto/Vagrant/Kubernetes/kubernetes-setup/master-playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
k8s-master                 : ok=15   changed=14   unreachable=0    failed=1

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Furthermore, what is interesting is even though it fails on this task, if I choose version Calico 3.14.

```
  - name: Install calico pod network
    become: false
    command: kubectl create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.14/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml
```

Also, by replacing the URL from `3.4` to `3.14`, the resources for the CNI underlay still will get created and they will still fail inside of the Vagrant machines:

```
vagrant@k8s-master:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-6bb5db574-p2w9c   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    10         31m
kube-system   calico-node-6wsm7                         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    7          13m
kube-system   calico-node-flf89                         0/1     Running             12         31m
kube-system   calico-node-fwk84                         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    6          12m
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-cdrb8                  0/1     ContainerCreating   0          31m
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-lgcf8                  0/1     ContainerCreating   0          31m
kube-system   etcd-k8s-master                           1/1     Running             0          31m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-master                 1/1     Running             0          31m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-master        1/1     Running             1          31m
kube-system   kube-proxy-79pw8                          1/1     Running             0          31m
kube-system   kube-proxy-g8gnm                          1/1     Running             0          12m
kube-system   kube-proxy-tvwlq                          1/1     Running             0          13m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-master                 1/1     Running             3          31m
```

Here are the messages:

```
vagrant@k8s-master:~$ kubectl logs -f calico-node-4q2xz -n kube-system
2020-08-22 21:35:41.194 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 299: Early log level set to info
2020-08-22 21:35:41.194 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 319: Using HOSTNAME environment (lowercase) for node name
2020-08-22 21:35:41.194 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 327: Determined node name: node-1
2020-08-22 21:35:41.195 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 106: Skipping datastore connection test
```

```
vagrant@k8s-master:~$ kubectl logs -f calico-kube-controllers-6bb5db574-m6b5j -n kube-system
2020-08-22 21:32:06.445 [INFO][1] main.go 88: Loaded configuration from environment config=&config.Config{LogLevel:"info", WorkloadEndpointWorkers:1, ProfileWorkers:1, PolicyWorkers:1, NodeWorkers:1, Kubeconfig:"", DatastoreType:"etcdv3"}
I0822 21:32:06.513751       1 client.go:357] parsed scheme: "endpoint"
I0822 21:32:06.514122       1 endpoint.go:68] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT> 0  <nil>}]
W0822 21:32:06.515723       1 client_config.go:541] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
W0822 21:32:06.538019       1 clientconn.go:1120] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT> 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT>: too many colons in address". Reconnecting...
2020-08-22 21:32:06.568 [INFO][1] main.go 109: Ensuring Calico datastore is initialized
W0822 21:32:07.541048       1 clientconn.go:1120] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT> 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT>: too many colons in address". Reconnecting...
W0822 21:32:09.309376       1 clientconn.go:1120] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT> 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT>: too many colons in address". Reconnecting...
W0822 21:32:12.223003       1 clientconn.go:1120] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT> 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT>: too many colons in address". Reconnecting...
W0822 21:32:15.736676       1 clientconn.go:1120] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT> 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT>: too many colons in address". Reconnecting...
{"level":"warn","ts":"2020-08-22T21:32:16.668Z","caller":"clientv3/retry_interceptor.go:61","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"endpoint://client-286ade6d-d04a-4dac-848b-231ef01101d2/http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT>","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address http://<ETCD_IP>:<ETCD_PORT>: too many colons in address\""}
2020-08-22 21:32:16.877 [ERROR][1] client.go 261: Error getting cluster information config ClusterInformation="default" error=context deadline exceeded
2020-08-22 21:32:16.907 [FATAL][1] main.go 114: Failed to initialize Calico datastore error=context deadline exceeded
```

Is this probably related to how the API gets provisioned in the Master-Playbook task within `master-playbook.yml`?

```
  - name: Initialize the Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm
    command: kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address="192.168.20.10" --apiserver-cert-extra-sans="192.168.20.10"  --node-name k8s-master --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

Here is a link where you can clone into an Ubuntu 16.04 env and it will have the same issues, more than Likely. Since this post was flagged for deletion, I decided to re-word this and make it more impactful as I still think it is very worthwhile to have up on Stackoverflow. More experienced people than me had a lot of problems with the Kubernetes Guide and even asked me.

Here is the link to that.
[Single Lab Link with Vagrant and Ansible](https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/KubeDeploy/tree/master/Virtualization/Vagrant/Kubernetes-Cluster/SingleMaster/Ubuntu1604-Kubernetes)

Ensure that you have the following tree structure when trying this out.
My main issue is basically how to get these Calico Pods working now:

```
sto@suplab02:~/Vagrant/Kubernetes$ tree
.
├── connect.sh
├── init.sh
├── join.sh
├── kubernetes-setup
│   ├── master-playbook.yml
│   └── node-playbook.yml
├── rename_roles.sh
└── Vagrantfile
```